# HTML form is not running a (withSuccessHandler)function

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I have this HTML form in Google App Script(Sheets) that asks a user for a date value and then to submit the value. The HTML form runs. the only problem is the obj doesn't log. I can't figure out why this is.

The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
   <form id="myForm">

    <input type="date" name="startDate" value="" id="demo" >
    <input type="button" style="font-family: verdana;" value="Submit" onclick="getStartDate()">

   </form> 
    <script>
  function success(msg) {
    alert(msg);
  }

  function getStartDate(){
    var form = document.getElementById("myForm").elements;
    var obj ={};
    for(var i = 0 ; i < form.length ; i++){
        var item = form.item(i);
        obj[item.name] = item.value;
    }
    google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(success)
    .getStartDate(obj);

    google.script.host.close();
  };
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The Javascript:

```
function getStartDate(obj){
  Logger.log(obj)
}
```

This should output the object but it doesn't.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- `google.script.run` works by the asynchronous processing. So in your script, `getStartDate()` and `success()` are not run due to `google.script.host.close()`.
- `getStartDate()` at GAS side doesn't return values. So `alert(msg)` shows `undefined`.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

HTML:

Please modify Javascript as follows.

```
function success(msg) {
  alert(JSON.stringify(msg)); // Modified
}

function getStartDate(){
  var form = document.getElementById("myForm").elements;
  var obj ={};
  for(var i = 0 ; i < form.length ; i++){
    var item = form.item(i);
    obj[item.name] = item.value;
  }
  google.script.run
  .withSuccessHandler(function(e) { // Modified
    success(e);
    google.script.host.close();
  })
  .getStartDate(obj);
};
```

GAS:

```
function getStartDate(obj){
  Logger.log(obj)
  return obj; // Modified
}
```

#### Note:

- If you want to give the key to `Submit`, please add `name` to `<input type="button" style="font-family: verdana;" value="Submit" onclick="getStartDate()">`.
- Of course, you can also move `google.script.host.close()` to `success()`.

#### Reference:

- [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

If this was not what you want, please tell me. I would like to modify it.