# Return a message based on html form input into a Google sheet upon verification

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I have been banging my head on the X for a while now on this. I have a Google Sheet, an HTML form and javascript which submits data to the sheet. My goal is to have the form submit data to the sheet, then check the sheet for the value of one of the fields that was submitted to see if it matches a cell in a column. That value has a corresponding value formatted as a date in the next column. If the input of the cell has a corresponding date that is “expired” I would like a message to return to the html page as a popup stating that It is expired. Any thoughts?

JS:

```
function submit_form() {    
// Check Fields
var complete = true;
var error_color = '#FFD9D9';
var fields = ['first_name','last_name','email','gs_code'];
var row = '';
var i;
for(i=0; i < fields.length; ++i) {
    var field = fields[i];
    $('#'+field).css('backgroundColor', 'inherit');
    var value = $('#'+field).val();       
    // Validate Field
    if(!value) {
        if(field != 'message') {
            $('#'+field).css('backgroundColor', error_color);
            var complete = false;
        }
        } else {            
        // Sheet Data
        row += '"'+value+'",';
    }
}

// Submission
if(complete) {      
    // Clean Row
    row = row.slice(0, -1);     
    // Config
    var gs_sid = ''; // Enter your Google Sheet ID here
    var gs_clid = ''; // Enter your API Client ID here
    var gs_clis = ''; // Enter your API Client Secret here
    var gs_rtok = ''; // Enter your OAuth Refresh Token here
    var gs_atok = false;
    var gs_url = ';
    var gs_body = '{"majorDimension":"ROWS", "values":[['+row+']]}';        
     // HTTP Request Token Refresh
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token?client_id='+gs_clid+'&client_secret='+gs_clis+'&refresh_token='+gs_rtok+'&grant_type=refresh_token');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.onload = function() {            
        var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        var gs_atok = response.access_token;            
        // HTTP Request Append Data
        if(gs_atok) {
            var xxhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xxhr.open('POST', gs_url);
            xxhr.setRequestHeader('Content-length', gs_body.length);
            xxhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
            xxhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + gs_atok );
            xxhr.onload = function() {
                if(xxhr.status == 200) {
                    // Success
                          $('audio#beep')[0].play();
                    $('#message').hide().html("Bottle has been Entered! Scan next Bottle.").fadeIn().delay('1000').fadeOut();

                    } 

                           else {
                    // Fail
                    $('#message').html('<p>Row Not Added</p><p>Response:<br/>'+xxhr.responseText+'</p>');
                }
            };
            xxhr.send(gs_body);
        }            
    };
    xhr.send();
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please read up on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), there's not much we can do without you providing some code to work from.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53465092/7215091

Comment: Thanks @ross... I modified the post to include my JS file. The HTML form is simple so I dont think you would really need that.

Comment: @Cooper... I think this might be on the right track but have to test. I will let you know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found this Google Apps Script that peforms the operation I am looking to do but now I need to figure out how to return the result back to the webpage that has the form

```
 <!-- Search Sheet for Bottle Expiration date -->

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/ID/edit#gid=1295319675");
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Entries");

function doGet(e){
 return search(e) ;
}  

function doPost(e){
 return search(e) ;
}  


function search(e){
 var id = e.parameter.last_name;

  var values = sheet.getRange(2, 2, sheet.getLastRow(),sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();

  for(var i = 0;i<values.length; i++){

    if(values[i][0] == id ){
      i=i+2;

      var name = sheet.getRange(i,4).getValue();
      var hydroDate = Date.now()+14;
      var hydroalert = ContentService.createTextOutput("Bottle is due for Hydro").setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT)
      if (hydroDate <= name)
      return hydroalert;
    }
  }
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("Id not found").setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);

}
```

```
<!-- HTML PAGE -->
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>UFD Tour 2 Monthlies</title>

    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen, handheld"/> -->


    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js?rev=<?php echo time();?>"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ufd_tour_2_monthlies.js?rev=<?php echo time();?>"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="qrscan.js?rev=<?php echo time();?>"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/sitepoint-editors/jsqrcode/master/src/qr_packed.js">
    </script>

      <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Place this within the <head> tag or just before the end of your <body> tag. -->
    <script src="https://awesome-table.com/AwesomeTableInclude.js"></script>
    </head>


    <style> 
    h2 {
       text-align: center;
      }
    input[type=text], input[type=password] { 
        width: 100%; 
        padding: 12px 20px; 
        margin: 8px 0; 
        display: inline-block; 
        border: 1px solid #ccc; 
        box-sizing: border-box; 
    } 
    button { 
        background-color: #4CAF50; 
        color: white; 
        padding: 14px 20px; 
        margin: 8px 0; 
        border: none; 
        cursor: pointer; 
        width: 100%; 
    } 
    .cancelbtn { 
        padding: 14px 20px; 
        background-color: #f44336; 
    } 
    .cancelbtn,.signupbtn { 
        float: left; 
        width: 50%; 
    } 

    .container { 
        padding: 16px; 
    } 


    .clearfix::after { 
        content: ""; 
        clear: both; 
        display: table; 
    } 


    @media screen and (max-width: 300px) { 
        .cancelbtn, .signupbtn { 
        width: 100%; 
        } 
    } 
      .form_container { width: 90%; max-width:450px; margin:20px 30px 40px 30px; padding:15px 20px; font-size:15px; line-height:25px; text-align:left; background:#EBEBEB; }
    .form_field { display:block; width:100%; height:30px; margin:5px 0px 10px 0px; padding:0px 10px; color:#333; font-size:16px; border:1px solid #999; border-radius:3px; -webkit-appearance:none; }
    .form_button { display:block; width:100%; height:35px; margin:20px 0px; padding:0px 0px; color:#FFF; font-size:16px; font-weight:bold; border:1px solid #3E7998; border-radius:3px; background:#3E7998; -webkit-appearance:none; }
    .form_message { }

      body, input {font-size:14pt}
    input, label {vertical-align:middle}
    .qrcode-text { display:block; width:90%; height:30px; margin:5px 0px 10px 0px; padding:0px 10px; color:#333; font-size:16px; border:1px solid #999; border-radius:3px; -webkit-appearance:none; }
    .qrcode-text-btn { display:block; text-align:center; width:90%; height:35px; margin:20px 0px; padding:0px 0px; color:#FFF; font-size:16px; font-weight:bold; border:1px solid #3E7998; border-radius:3px; background:#3E7998; -webkit-appearance:none; }
    .qrcode-text-btn > input[type=file] {position:absolute; overflow:hidden; width:1px; height:1px; opacity:0}
    </style> 
    <body> 

    <h2>Tour 2 Monthlies</h2> 


    <div class="container"> 
         <form id="sheets" name="sheets" class="form_body">
           <label for="first_name">Date</label>
    <input id="first_name" name="first_name" type="date" class="form_field" value="" placeholder="Select Date"/>
           <label for="last_name">Bottle Number</label>
    <input id="last_name" name="last_name" class="form_field" onfocus="this.value='';" value="" placeholder="Select here to scan or enter manually"/>
           <input type="button" name="btnScanBarcode" id="btnScanBarcode" class="form_button" value="Scan Bottle" onclick="javascript:openQRCamera(this);"></button>

     <!-- <input id="last_name" name="last_name" type=text placeholder="Select here to scan or enter manually" class="qrcode-text"><label class="qrcode-text-btn"><input type=file accept="image/*" capture=environment onclick="openQRCamera(this);" tabindex=-1>Scan Bottle</label> 

      <script>function openQRCamera(node) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function() {
        node.value = "";
        qrcode.callback = function(res) {
          if(res instanceof Error) {
            alert("No QR code found. Please make sure the QR code is within the camera's frame and try again.");
          } else {
            node.parentNode.previousElementSibling.value = res;
          }
        };
        qrcode.decode(reader.result);
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(node.files[0]);
    }</script> -->

      <script>
    function startBarcodeScanner() 
    {    

        window.location.href = 'bwstw://startscanner?field=last_name';
    }

    </script>
           <label for="email">Bottle Location</label>
    <select id="email" name="email" class="form_field" value="" placeholder="Bottle Location"/>
      <option>ENGINE 1</option>
    <option>ENGINE 2</option>
    <option>ENGINE 3</option>
    <option>SQUAD 4</option>
    <option>SQUAD 41</option>
    <option>LADDER 1</option>
    <option>TRUCK 1</option>
    <option>TRUCK 2</option>
    <option>TRUCK 3</option>
    <option>ENGINE 5</option>
    <option>ENGINE 6</option>
    <option>ENGINE 7</option>
    <option>RESCUE 1</option>
    <option>RESCUE 2</option>
    <option>RESCUE 3</option>
    <option>STATION 1 SPARE</option>
    <option>STATION 2 SPARE</option>
    <option>STATION 3 SPARE</option>
    <option>SPECIAL OPS</option>
    <option>BC</option>
    <option>COD</option>
    <option>DC</option>
    <option>EMSC</option>
    <option>FINV</option>
    <option>COMM</option>
    <option>TRAIN</option>
    <option>BOAT</option>
    <option>SPARE MASK</option>
    <option>O/S</option>
    <option>OTHER LOCATION</option>
    <option>OTHER VEHICLE</option>
      </select>


    <input id="gs_code" name="gs_code" type="hidden" class="" value="=VLOOKUP(B:B,HydroBottles,4,FALSE)" placeholder=""/>
        <div class="clearfix"> 

         <input id="submit" name="submit" type="button" class="form_button" value="Enter Bottle" onClick="submit_form(); document.getElementById('last_name').value = ''; playAudio()"/>
             <audio id="beep">
      <source src="bleep.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>

    <div class="form_message" id="message">





          </div>
        </div> 
    </div> 

      <!-- Place this tag where you want the Awesome Table Widget to render -->
    <div data-type="AwesomeTableView" data-viewID="-LfNI2wu42vUdIl5oy9c"></div>


    </form> 
    </body> 
    </html>
```